# Django tutorial part 5. Indexview testing doesn't get message "No polls are available."

Tags: django

I tried to run the testing on django tutorial part 5. But I couldn't pass.

The test class is like below

```
class QuestionIndexViewTests(TestCase):

def test_no_questions(self):
    """
    If no questions exists, an appropriate message is displayed
    """

    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

def test_future_question(self):
    """
    Questions with a pub_date in the future aren't displayed on
    the index page.
    """
    create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

def test_past_question(self):
    """
    Questions with pub_date in the past are displayed on the index page
    """

    create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['latest_question_list'],
        ['<Question: Past question.>']
    )

def test_future_question_and_past_question(self):
    """
    Even if both past and future questions exist, only past questions
    are displayed
    """

    create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
    create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['latest_question_list'],
        ['<Question: Past question.>']
    )

def test_two_past_questions(self):
    """
    The questions index page may display multiple questions.
    """
    create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
    create_question(question_text="Past question 2.", days=-5)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['latest_question_list'],
        ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>']
    )
```

Errors occured in functions test_future_question and test_future_question_and_past_question.
I able passed the test when I commented out the statements 
   'self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")'
It seems like I need to pass the message from view when there is no questions.
But I have no idea how to pass the message.
My view class is like below.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'polls/index.html'
context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
    published in the future)
    """
    return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: "Errors occured" -- which errors?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. My time variable was incorrect.

check your code around the function create question. Below is what I had to fix.

```
'''
def create_question(question_text, days): 
    time = timezone.now() +    datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    return    Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)
```